# Refreshing Datagrid in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I  have this project where in I have to add file to my datagrid, then when i click it, i can able to edit or delete the file that i've added. here is a sample screen shot of my form

[image]

when I click add, the file that is in the textbox will be added to the datagrid. and it do work.

Then When i click on the data in my data grid, The file name will be inserted in my textbox in able me to edit it. Then when i click edit, the grid must refresh showing the edited file. Same with the delete.

The problem is when I tried to edit or delete my file and refresh my grid, an error show.

I'm sure the file is edited/deleted but I didn't refresh my grid instead It give me error.

[image]

Here is my code in refreshing my grid. I call this method whenever I click on Add/edit/delete button

```
 public void DisplaySourceFile()
    {

        try
        {
            if (CONN.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                CONN.Open();
            }


            CMD = new SqlCommand("Select sf_id as [ID], sf_name as [FILES] from [Source_File] where s_id = @s_id", CONN);
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_id", SourceId);
            DA = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD);
            DT = new DataTable("Role");
            DA.Fill(DT);
            dataGridFile.ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView;

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (CONN.ToString() != String.Empty && CONN.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                CONN.Close();
        }

    }
```

Here my code when selecting item in my datagrid:

```
 private void dataGridFile_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bo_source = new BO.BO_Source();
        dal_source = new DAL.DAL_Source();
        //Check if there is selected item

            dal_source.selectedSourceFile = Convert.ToInt32((DT.Rows[dataGridFile.SelectedIndex])[0].ToString());

        selectedSource = dal_source.selectedSourceFile;
        btnEdit.IsEnabled = true;
        btnDelete.IsEnabled = true;
        btnAdd.IsEnabled = false;

        if (dal_source.GetSourceFileInfo(bo_source) == true)
        {
            txtFileName.Text = bo_source.sf_name;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: instead of going the current approach I would advice you to go for MVVM approach which is more WPF way, so before I answer your question, tell me if you are willing to go for MVVM or you'll stay with what you have.

Comment: I'm using layering right know.

Comment: layered code is nice to have but what I can see from the code you've share is a tight coupling between layers. so wondering if you intend to revise that or leave it as it is.

Comment: Im intense to leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see from what you've shared is that in error is referring to row at index -1.

Since any index starts from 0 so -1 is not possible to edit or delete.

So the solution for this scenario is to manage the index

- it should not go below 0 when you delete first or last row
- also it should not go above max rows-1 when you delete last row

and if it cross any boundary you need to handle accordingly.

the issue seems to be here

```
//Check if there is selected item
dal_source.selectedSourceFile = Convert.ToInt32((DT.Rows[dataGridFile.SelectedIndex])[0].ToString());
```

so perhaps change it to validate the

```
//Check if there is selected item
int selectedIndex = dataGridFile.SelectedIndex;
if(selectedIndex > -1 && selectedIndex < DT.Rows.Count)
{
    dal_source.selectedSourceFile = Convert.ToInt32((DT.Rows[selectedIndex])[0].ToString());

    selectedSource = dal_source.selectedSourceFile;
    btnEdit.IsEnabled = true;
    btnDelete.IsEnabled = true;
    btnAdd.IsEnabled = false;

    if (dal_source.GetSourceFileInfo(bo_source) == true)
    {
        txtFileName.Text = bo_source.sf_name;
    }
}
```

this should solve your current issue.

**MVVM way**

in this approach bind your model with the data grid as ObservableCollection and then manipulate the collection instead of working on UI elements, so removal or addition or refresh will be handled by WPF's powerful binding framework

Comment: I dont even know why it keep on telling me that I have a row at index -1 even if I dont Have any.

Comment: it may be due to the reason that you may be attempting to use SelectedIndex when no row is selected. Could you share full code at pastebin.com so we can have a look

Comment: updated the answer the error was in `DT.Rows[dataGridFile.SelectedIndex]`

Comment: I've find out something to resolve my this problem. tnx